# How to select NOT element with specific string in colon attributed name

Tags: html, css, typescript, webdriver, protractor

I have couple of elements like this:

```
<g transform="matrix">
   <image xlink:href="data:image/png" width="48">
</g>
<g transform="matrix">
   <image xlink:href="specyfic" width="48">
</g>
<g transform="matrix">
   <image xlink:href="specyfic" width="48">
</g>
```

I want to select element which would NOT have 'specifyc' in name. The problem is that sometimes there are couple of that NOT elements and sometimes there are none. The NON specyfic image count is always one.

I cannot accomplish that because of ':' in attribute name.

I tried this:

```
  public static getEventIconOnMap: ElementFinder = 
   element.all(by.css('image[width="48"]:not(image[xlink\\:href*="specyfic"'))).last();
```

Comment: It's better to give example HTML, thus we can try on local

Comment: So, you want to select every image that does not contain the work 'specyfic' in it. Is this correct?

Comment: I can't help you with a complete answer, but looking at the answers so far, I think you're missing a critical bit of the question. Your markup is svg, presumably embedded in a HTML page. That means that the markup is foreign content and XML namespacing applies. So in CSS that would mean using the pipe character instead of backslash-colon. Since declaring the namespace-prefix binding looks hard (possibly impossible) I'd try using * for all prefixed attributes. So you could try something like `image[width="48"]:not([*|href*='specyfic'])`

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not make much sense to me and have no idea how to test it, but I think the following code will work. Try escaping the character like this:

```
public static getEventIconOnMap: ElementFinder = 
   element.all(by.css('image:not([xlink\:href*=specyfic]')).last();
```

Here is a CSS selector that works, so adjust this to your code:

```
image:not([xlink\:href*=specyfic]) {
  // your code
}
```

Here is a working fiddle - it's not the exact code you are using, but I wrote it as a css selector: https://jsfiddle.net/x4gsr658/

Comment: css alternative is good, but please note the selector used `[attribute*=` is not the same as `[attribute~=`. For example specyficcccc would return as a match since the `*` selector just looks for a value, and `~` looks for a word

Comment: I know the difference, but the OP said 'NOT have 'specyfic' in name', so it could be placed anywhere within the attribute.